# Body text in R with RDCOMClient

Tags: r

I created a code to send emails in R, it works almost perfectly well but with this code, if I sent the email, it will be in only one paragraph, like that

one two three

But i need it to be in different paragraphs, like that:

one

two

three

Probably is an very simple way of doing it, but i'am completely stuck in this

Thats the code:

```
library (RDCOMClient)

outMail$GetInspector()
signature = outMail[["HTMLbody"]]
signature
 
outMail[["To"]] = "email@email"
outMail[["CC"]] = "email2@email.com"
outMail[["subject"]] = "Subject"
outMail[["Attachments"]]$Add("C:\\Users\\name\\Folder\\Folder2\\Excel.xlsx")
outMail[["HTMLBody"]] = paste0("one two three", signature)

outMail$Display()
outMail$Send()
```

Comment: Does adding "\n", e.g. ..."one\n\ntwo\n\n..." not create multiple lines?

Comment: I was trying that just now but it didn't...

Comment: I was trying to use writeLines and actually, it worked, It was just what I was looking for. However, when I execute the outMail$Display(), the body from the email is empty. I tryed to save it in a variable but I coudn't, after I print it, the result is Null. Is there a way I can save it in a variable?